# android webview flash fullscreen

Tags: android, flash, webview, fullscreen

In my application has the `WebView` and embedded flash player, I need to run it in full screen mode.

Since the beginning of the application fell when trying to go to full screen mode,
I then described:

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient (new WebChromeClient ());
```

application ceased to fall, but the `WebView` is lost (becomes transparent?)

any ideas how to fix this? may need to give focus to the `WebView` again. help

p.s. android is 4.0